# Does Clickhouse server account for max_threads settings at runtime without restart?

Tags: clickhouse

We have some spare cores we could free up under high workload for our application as it has many requests. Can we reconfigure "max_threads" to higher settings at runtime?

Is there limitations in increasing max_threads or potentially decreasing max_threads later  (like increasinf possible, but not decreasind)?

Comment: `echo '<clickhouse><profiles><profile_name><max_threads>10</max_threads></profile_name></profiles></clickhouse>' > /etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/max_threads.xml`

or add `SETTINGS max_threads=10` at the end of query

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests as I could not find the answer. @Slach provided a way to pass it in the query and have control on app side, but question was about control the ClickHouse server behaviour.
Settings in config will be applied at runtime, no need to restart.

We changed the user config under
`

```
/etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/
```

([Official Clickhouse documentation "Configuration Files"](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/configuration-files) )

Any settings there will be applied at runtime. And Clickhouse applies those changes pretty quickly.